# a proof in Matsumura's book

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have a problem for the proof of Theorem 4.2 in the book Commutative ring theory by Matsumura.

> Localization commutes with passing to quotients by ideals. More precisely, let $A$ be a ring, $S\subset A$ a multiplicative set, $I$ an ideal of $A$ and $\bar S$ the image of $S$ in $A/I$; then
>
> $A_S/I_S\cong (A/I)_{\bar S}$.
>
> Proof. Both sides has the universal property for ring homomorphisms $g: A\to C$ such that
>
> (1) every element of $S$ maps to a unit of $C$.
>
> (2) every elements of $I$ maps to $0$.
>
> the isomorphism follows by the uniqueness of the solution to a universal mapping problem.

I actually can prove this theorem by consider the map $a/s$ mod  $IA_S$ to $\bar a / \bar s$. Everything is ritual in this way.

But his above argument seems difficult to me. In fact, what is the solution of mapping problem and how does it apply to the proof ?

Comment: I think what he's saying is that if you have two objects, both of which satisfy some property that you've already proven to be universal, then the two objects are isomorphic. This is actually what allows us to define things by universal properties.

Comment: I agree with @M10687 's interpretation. "Both sides have the universal property", then to rephrase the quote "uniqueness of the solution to a universal mapping problem" to "the solution of the universal mapping problem is unique" i.e. "the object which satisfies the universal property is unique". (Of course the "uniqueness" is up to isomorphism, as M10687 also pointed out.)